# Enum Switch statement Java 6 "Default" case

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

```
private enum CLASS {FMAN, SOPH, JUN, SEN, GRAD, ERROR};

private CLASS stringToClass(String t){

    switch(CLASS.valueOf(t))
    {
    case FMAN: return CLASS.FMAN;
    case SOPH: return CLASS.SOPH;
    case JUN: return CLASS.JUN;
    case SEN: return CLASS.SEN;
    case GRAD: return CLASS.GRAD;
    default: 
        System.out.println("NOT VALID CLASS. ERROR");
        return CLASS.ERROR;
    }
}
```

So I have this piece of code right here. While constructing, I have this method to return corresponding values from a given string t.

My question is, lets say "t" ends up being "CSE". How do I handle that and basically return the value of CLASS.ERROR.?

This is in Java 6, not 7 by the way.

Comment: Calling an enum a class... ow my brain.

Comment: I know I know. It can be confusing. Bad naming on my part. But I already have classification taken in my code.

Comment: Well, if t ends up being "CSE", for example, because CLASS.CSE does not exist, it does not return CLASS.ERROR as intended. Instead, I get an error, saying CLASS.CSE does not exist.

Comment: How to handle it? Use a `try-catch` block code to handle the error.

Comment: Like I said, since CLASS.CSE does not exist, it just stops what its doing.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a better way to write this:

```
private CLASS stringToClass(String t){
    try {
        return CLASS.valueOf(t);
    } catch (InvalidArgumentException ex) {
        return CLASS.ERROR;
    }
}
```

The switch statement is redundant ... and it actually makes your code more fragile 'cos you have to remember update the case list if you add new values to the `enum`.

---

I should also point out a couple of stylistic atrocities in your code:

- Calling an enum "CLASS" is horribly misleading.
- You are using the wrong kind of identifier.  All type names should be written using camel case, and start with an uppercase letter.  (Names that are acronyms can be treated as exceptional, but CLASS is not an acronym.)

> I know I know. It can be confusing. Bad naming on my part. But I already have classification taken in my code.

Yea ... well, change it to something else.  Use your imagination.  But don't break the style rules.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with StevenC's answer, but I would:

- rename the enum to a more stylistically acceptable name
- roll the method into the enum
- rename the method so it makes sense in the context of the enum class name
- name the Exception parameter `ignore` (the conventional way to indicate it's being ignored)
- strip off the qualifying enum class name from with the method

Leaving this:

```
private enum ClassLevel {
    FMAN, SOPH, JUN, SEN, GRAD, ERROR;

    static ClassLevel parseString(String t) {
        try {
            return valueOf(t);
        } catch (InvalidArgumentException ignore) {
            return ERROR;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the `parseString` should be declared to return `ClassLevel`.